# Stop Pandas from converting int to float due to an insertion in another column

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, type-inference

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns: a column of `int` and a column of `str`.

- I understand that if I insert `NaN` into the `int` column, Pandas will convert all the `int` into `float` because there is no `NaN` value for an `int`.
- However, when I insert `None` into the `str` column, Pandas converts all my `int` to `float` as well. This doesn't make sense to me - why does the value I put in column 2 affect column 1?

Here's a simple working example):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["int"] = pd.Series([], dtype=int)
df["str"] = pd.Series([], dtype=str)

df.loc[0] = [0, "zero"]
print(df)
print()

df.loc[1] = [1, None]
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
   int   str
0    0  zero

   int   str
0  0.0  zero
1  1.0   NaN
```

Is there any way to make the output the following:

```
   int   str
0    0  zero

   int   str
0    0  zero
1    1   NaN
```

without recasting the first column to `int`.

- I prefer using `int` instead of `float` because the actual data in
  that column are integers. If there's not workaround, I'll just
  use `float` though.
- I prefer not having to recast because in my actual code, I don't
  store the actual `dtype`.
- I also need the data inserted row-by-row.

Comment: This works the same way not only if any column value `None` but if `float` too.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you set `dtype=object`, your series will be able to contain arbitrary data types:

```
df["int"] = pd.Series([], dtype=object)
df["str"] = pd.Series([], dtype=str)
df.loc[0] = [0, "zero"]
print(df)
print()
df.loc[1] = [1, None]
print(df)

   int   str
0    0  zero
1  NaN   NaN

  int   str
0   0  zero
1   1  None
```

Comment: You cannot imagine how this one helped me, reading in a csv with 200 columns... I actually experimented with with a elaborate dict for the dtypes, only to start over and over again. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure `dtype=str` is correct. I think it's the same as `dtype=object`. The correct syntax is `dtype="string"` or `dtype=pandas.StringDtype()`.

Answer (score 18):

As of pandas 1.0.0 I believe you have another option, which is to first use [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html). This converts the dataframe columns to dtypes that support pd.NA, avoiding the issues with NaN/None.

```
...

df = df.convert_dtypes()
df.loc[1] = [1, None]
print(df)

#   int   str
# 0   0  zero
# 1   1  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `DataFrame.append` to add the data, the dtypes are preserved, and you do not have to recast or rely on `object`:

```
In [157]: df
Out[157]:
   int   str
0    0  zero

In [159]: df.append(pd.DataFrame([[1, None]], columns=['int', 'str']), ignore_index=True)
Out[159]:
   int   str
0    0  zero
1    1  None
```

Comment: Not true: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a1"]) ; df.append(pd.DataFrame([[1, 200]], columns=['a1', 'a2']), ignore_index=True)` prints `0  1  200.0`, where the 200.0 is obviously a float.

Comment: Sure, but if you specify that `a2` has dtype `float` on creation (which is the case in OP), `append` still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

right after

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

add the below and it will initialize the entire series to int.  This worked for me.

```
df['int'] = 0
```