# preventing pandas.DataFrame.loc from typecasting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

If we initialise a `pandas.DataFrame` where the type will be `int64`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)), columns=['one','two'])
```

and then typecast the first column to be `np.str` and look at the second row:

(1)

```py
df2 = df1.astype({'one':np.str}) 
df2.loc[1,]
```

`df2.loc[1,]` returns a pandas.Series having type `object`, with the elements' types preserved.

However, if we typecast the second first column to be `np.float`

(2)

```py
df3 = df1.astype({'one':np.float})
df3.loc[1,]
```

`df3.loc[1,]` returns a pandas.Series having type `float64`, i.e. the int64 in column `'two'` was promoted to `float64`.

Is there a way to ensure that `df.loc` always preserves type as in (1) avoid the behaviour in (2)?

(And why would I care? Because ints can be passed as indexes, floats can't, and I'm slightly annoyed of having to recast objects because pandas decided that what I wanted as return value isn't what I had put into my dataframe originally)

Comment: with `df3.loc[1,] ` you are accessing the first row, NOT the 'two' column. you can see that `df3.info()` preserves the dtype of column `two` to int64.

Comment: @vb_rises, I put in an 'int' in `df1` out  comes a float from `df3.loc[1,]`.  And as you point out df3.info()  says that there is an `int`in there so somewhere the type changed to `float` when the value was returned. And I suspect that `loc` is doing that, which I don't want.

Comment: What is the output you are actually expecting, can you post that? df.loc() functions is designed to return a Series, hence it will cast to the dtype where all the values can be fit. If you want to access particular element from every row, then you can do `df3.loc[1:,'two']` and it returns int. Here 1 = 1st row, so you can iterate and fetch relevant element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine ints and floats in a series, it will cast the ints as floats as you have discovered. One way to get around this is by setting dtype=object in your dataframe like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)), columns=['one','two'], dtype=object)

df2 = df1.astype({'one':np.str}) 
df2.loc[1,]

one    2
two    3
Name: 1, dtype: object

df3 = df1.astype({'one':np.float})
df3.loc[1,]

one    2
two    3
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252138/2740563)